# Java - how to setup socks proxy with credentials

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection, socks, authenticator

Hi There Dear Community Members,
i am a begginer and i am trying to setup a socks proxy with credentials so i used the following code. but it's not working.

```
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("myhost.com", 81));
Authenticator.setDefault(new ProxyAuthenticator("aaa","aaa"));
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
```

i am getting error

```
java.net.SocketException: SOCKS : authentication failed
```

i even tried the following code but its not working too.

```
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("myhost.com", 81));
System.setProperty("java.net.socks.username","aaa");
System.setProperty("java.net.socks.password","aaa");
```

i tried to combine them, i tried to use `System.setProperty("socksProxyUser","aaa")` and `System.setProperty("socksProxyPassword","aaa")` but i am still getting the same error. Can Anyone Please Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this when attempting to authenticate.

```
public Authenticator getAuth(String user, String password) {
    new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray()));
        }
    };
}
```

Then, normally initialize your proxy Like how youre doing, except with the authentication (The reason why youre getting an error), do this.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(getAuth(username, password));
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without Authenticator.setDefault()?  my use case is multi threaded.